# Preventing system processes from using GPU

Tags: nvidia, compiz, gpu, xserver, integrated

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, and am currently setting up a machine for dedicated GPU programming. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an Asus desktop with integrated graphics. It might be worth noting that I was able to run without issue with no GPU installed. I have already successfully installed CUDA to run on an Nvidia GeForce GTX Titan GK110, and set the BIOS to run main diplay graphics from the iGPU. Nonetheless, nvidia-smi gives me the folloing readout:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TITAN   Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P8    14W / 250W |    216MiB /  6082MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1015    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             107MiB |
|    0      3654    G   compiz                                         107MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Unless I'm mistaken, this suggests that X server and compiz are still running on the GPU. I would very much prefer that they run on integrated graphics instead. Is there a way to change this using OS settings? Any clarification would be appreciated.